# Carrierwave Direct gem not redirecting after successful upload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

When I upload a file it goes through to my s3 bucket and is all fine there but for some reason my app doesn't redirect? It just stays on the same page. I had a look at the logs and nothing changes, nor do I get back any key.

Heres my form:

```
= direct_upload_form_for @uploader do |f|
  = f.file_field :text_file
  = f.submit
```

and my controller

```
  def upload
    @uploader = Submission.new.text_file
    @uploader.success_action_redirect = new_submission_path
  end
```

Comment: you should give Hammand Khalid credit for giving you a correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting `success_action_redirect` to a relative path, you need to set it to a full url:

```
def upload
  @uploader = Submission.new.text_file
  @uploader.success_action_redirect = root_url
end
```

Comment: this is the correct answer---too bad @Harazzy never gave credit.  I'm quit amazing this question and answer are voted up, this has to be a common error.